# How to get rid of "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Tags: reactjs

How do i get rid of that warning from the code below?

At first i had the key={linkList[index]} but that also gave me a separate warning.. adding +10 to it solved the first warning but I cant seem to figure out this other one.

```
   const linkList = [
        <Link style={linkStyle} to={{
            pathname: `${props.ideaslink}`,
            state: {
                savemessage1: props.saveMessage1,
                savemessage2: props.saveMessage2,
            }
        }} >Ideas</Link>,
        <Link style={linkStyle} onClick={() => props.showContact(true)} >Contact</Link>,
        <Link style={linkStyle} onClick={() => props.showInfo(true)} >How it Works</Link>]
```

```
{trail.map(({ x, height, ...rest }, index) => (
 <animated.div
   key={linkList[index + 10]}
   className="trails-text"
   style={{ ...rest, transform: x.interpolate(x => `translate3d(${x}px,0,0)`) }}>
   {linkList[index]}
 </animated.div>
```

Comment: Did you make sure that all items within linkList are unique?

Comment: They are all a Link component... I added the list above

Comment: Add `key` prop to each `<Link ..` you kept in `linkList`

Comment: Thank you! It works when adding key={1} + to each link in Link list and changing inside the map to  key={linkList[index].key}.